# how can we deploy new dashboards and widgets from sonar test environment to production environment

Tags: testing, sonarqube, production

In previous posting from 2009, it seemed like there was a way to deploy new dashboards and widgets, etc from a sonar test / staging environment to a production environment.

This is documented in ...
http://www.sonarqube.org/romoting-sonar-configuration-from-staging-to-production-environment/

We are using SonarQube v4.5.1.

Is there still a way to do this in our SonarQube version?

If not, is there another option other than manually creating the dashboards/widgets/etc?

Thanks